# How can i apply css when a query string is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i want to do is (at the end of the body) check for a query string and apply css depending on what it is.

www.example.com
Will do nothing

www.example.com/example--location/example.html?theme=Red
will add the 'red' css

www.example.com/example-path/example2.html?theme=yellow
will ass the 'yellow' css

Also, if possible, i need the theme to follow them to other urls on my site when they click a link/tab.

Comment: Please add the codes you have tried :)

Comment: @Biswas I have never worked with QueryStrings, I know how to use them in .asp, however I need to do this in html/javascript.

Comment: you can refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: Why did you accept my answer then unaccept it (and downvoted it maybe)? It is working fine and addresses all the points in your question.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I can't downvote(Note my reputation), and I managed to find a solution that suits my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Javascript function to retrieve qs paramaters **window.location.search** then parse them to check that the one you want is there, then change the stylesheet reference in your HTML using **getElementById**.

Answer (score 0):

You'll at least need JavaScript for that.

First you need a function that can read the variables in the URL:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if(pair[0] == variable){
          return pair[1];}
      }
   return(false);
}
```

Now let's say you want to change the css of the element with id `element1`

```
if(getQueryVariable("theme") == "red") {
    document.getElementById("element1").className = "redClass";
} elseif(getQueryVariable("theme") == "yellow") {
    document.getElementById("element1").className = "yellowClass";
}
```

Of course you need to create the css classes (in this example `redClass` and `yelloClass`) first, but that's pretty much how it could work out.

**edit**: As requested by OP, here's a working demo. JsFiddle apparently doesn't like GET parameters, so just copy it to an html file an try for yourself. `?theme=red` will make the text red. `?theme=yellow` will make the text yellow.

```
<style>
.redClass {
    color: red;
}

.yellowClass {
    color: yellow;
}
</style>

<div id="element1">This is a test</div>

<script>
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if(pair[0] == variable){
          return pair[1];}
      }
   return(false);
}

if(getQueryVariable("theme") == "red") {
    document.getElementById("element1").className = "redClass";
} else if(getQueryVariable("theme") == "yellow") {
    document.getElementById("element1").className = "yellowClass";
}

</script>
```

Comment: That is not what OP asked for.

Comment: Is there a chance of you posting an example where a box changes css depending on the tag?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a function that will parse your URL parameters (query string) from the [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Properties) property; then, once you have the parameter, apply that class to your `<body>` tag.

```
function getUrlParameters() {
  var params = {};
  if (location.search) {
    var parts = location.search.substring(1).split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var nv = parts[i].split('=');
        if (!nv[0]) continue;
        params[nv[0]] = nv[1] || true;
    }
  }
  return params;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var theme = getUrlParameters().theme;
  if (theme)
    $("body").addClass(theme);
});
```